The commands are not running in Trace32 Tool
This is the code. Trace32 tool is opening but no commands is executing. What to do?
process=subprocess.Popen([t32_exe,'-s', start_up],stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
command="REACHED"
time.sleep(5)
process.stdin.write(command.encode())
process.stdin.flush()

This is the code. Trace32 tool is opening but no commands is executing. What to do?
t32 is path to trace 32.exe and start_up is  config.t32. file path

There are demos in the TRACE32 installation showing how to send commands to a PowerView instance using Python (“PYRCL”) or by using the t32rem executable (although you'd need to enable a port for this in the T32 configuration file).
To enable the remote API port, you would add RCL=NETASSIST (above and below lines should be empty) in your config.t32 file; or if using T32Start, set Interfaces → API Port → Use Port to "yes".
One installation folder to look at is ~~~~/demo/api/python, where some of the files have subprocess.Popen e.g. ./tests/test_connection.py
